# Strange Mitotic phase of oocytes in primary follicles

Tags: histology, germination

In the process of learning about the reproductive system, I find  an oocyte enveloped by a single layer of follicular cells appears to be undergoing equal division, resembling a primary follicle located near the ovarian tunica albuginea. This slice is from rabbit ovaries, stained with HE, 40 * 10.

**What puzzing** me is: It seems that the oocyte should not undergo mitosis at this time, and I am not sure how to explain this phenomenon?
My initial idea is whether it is possible to have multiple oocytes simultaneously in the follicles of rabbits. I tried to searche on PubMed and Google, but found no relevant evidence.

[image: rabbit ovaries, stained with HE, 40 * 10]

PS: Because the file size is limited to less than 2M, the image here only captures a portion of the field of view. If you need a complete picture, please leave a message.